# Inkscape Inquiry: Why my defined page dimensions won't visually match an imported image?

Tags: inkscape

.. of the same dimensions?

[image]

The imported image at 2048x2048 looks larger than the page defined at the SAME dimensions (in the Custom size area). It makes no sense.

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the image import dialog, Inkscape asks you for the dpi value it should use for the raster image. Use the defult import resolution after making sure it is set to 96 dpi for Inkscape >= 0.92 (90 for older versions) in Edit > Preferences > Bitmaps (or Edit > Preferences > Imported Images in Inkscape 1.0), to have the pixels match those in Inkscape.

Comment: The only other choice is "Default import resolution" (see 2nd uploaded image), is that what you mean?